# Selector check if class exist on same level

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is my snippet :

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
 //$(".tree-node").parents('.tree-child-folders').css("color", "red");
  //$(".tree-collapsed:has(.tree-child-folders)").css("color", "red");
  $(".tree-node > .tree-collapsed:has(.tree-child-folders)").css("color", "red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tree-node">
  <span class="tree-child-folders tree-line">TEST1</span>
  <span class="tree-collapsed">CHANGE COLOR</span>
  <span class="tree-test">TEST3</span>
</div>

<div class="tree-node">
  <span class="tree-child-folders tree-line">TEST4</span>
  <span class="tree-other">TEST5</span>
  <span class="tree-test">TEST6</span>
</div>

<div class="tree-node">
  <span class="tree-line">TEST7</span>
  <span class="tree-collapsed">TEST8</span>
  <span class="tree-test">TEST9</span>
</div>
```

I would like to put the color red to the `<span>` which contain the class `.tree-collapsed` and on the same level a `<span>` contain the class `.tree-child-folders`

I would like to know if it's possible to do it using only CSS ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its doable using css with general successor sibling selector `~` (*meaning the element comes after this one, but not necessarily immediately after*) or next sibling selector `+`

```css
.tree-node > .tree-child-folders ~ .tree-collapsed {
color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="tree-node">
  <span class="tree-child-folders tree-line">TEST1</span>
  <span class="tree-collapsed">CHANGE COLOR</span>
  <span class="tree-test">TEST3</span>
</div>

<div class="tree-node">
  <span class="tree-child-folders tree-line">TEST4</span>
  <span class="tree-other">TEST5</span>
  <span class="tree-test">TEST6</span>
</div>

<div class="tree-node">
  <span class="tree-line">TEST7</span>
  <span class="tree-collapsed">TEST8</span>
  <span class="tree-test">TEST9</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you specifically want to do this with jQuery (not with CSS), you can use a [sibling combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#sibling-combinators) provided the `.tree-child-folders` element is before the `.tree-collapsed` element. For instance, with the "[subsequent sibling combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#general-sibling-combinators)" (`~`):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tree-node > .tree-child-folders ~ .tree-collapsed").css("color", "red");
});
```

Live Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tree-node > .tree-child-folders ~ .tree-collapsed").css("color", "red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tree-node">
  <span class="tree-child-folders tree-line">TEST1</span>
  <span class="tree-collapsed">CHANGE COLOR</span>
  <span class="tree-test">TEST3</span>
</div>

<div class="tree-node">
  <span class="tree-child-folders tree-line">TEST4</span>
  <span class="tree-other">TEST5</span>
  <span class="tree-test">TEST6</span>
</div>

<div class="tree-node">
  <span class="tree-line">TEST7</span>
  <span class="tree-collapsed">TEST8</span>
  <span class="tree-test">TEST9</span>
</div>
```

If that order isn't reliable, though, I don't see an alternative to looping:

```
// Find all `.tree-node > .tree-collapsed` and loop through them
$(".tree-node > .tree-collapsed").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    // Does this parent also contain a `.tree-child-folders`?
    if ($this.parent().find(".tree-child-folders").length) {
        // Yes, make it red
        $this.css("color", "red");
    }
});
```

Live Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Find all `.tree-node > .tree-collapsed` and loop through them
    $(".tree-node > .tree-collapsed").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        // Does this parent also contain a `.tree-child-folders`?
        if ($this.parent().find(".tree-child-folders").length) {
            // Yes, make it red
            $this.css("color", "red");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tree-node">
  <span class="tree-child-folders tree-line">TEST1</span>
  <span class="tree-collapsed">CHANGE COLOR</span>
  <span class="tree-test">TEST3</span>
</div>

<div class="tree-node">
  <span class="tree-child-folders tree-line">TEST4</span>
  <span class="tree-other">TEST5</span>
  <span class="tree-test">TEST6</span>
</div>

<div class="tree-node">
  <span class="tree-line">TEST7</span>
  <span class="tree-collapsed">TEST8</span>
  <span class="tree-test">TEST9</span>
</div>
```